# JUnit & hamcrest: could containsInAnyOrder() tell more about the mismatch?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, hamcrest

While testing a `Set` with JUnit and [Hamcrest Matchers](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html) I've noticed that `Matchers.contains()` method gives a pretty good clue on what's wrong with the test. On the other hand `Matchers.containsInAnyOrder()` difference report is almost useless. Here's the test code:

**Simple bean:**

```
public class MyBean {
    private Integer id;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }       
}
```

**JUnit test:**

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.junit.Test;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class MyTest {

    @Test
    public void hamcrestTest() {
        Set<MyBean> beanSet = new HashSet<MyBean>();

        MyBean bean = new MyBean();
        bean.setId(1);
        beanSet.add(bean);

        bean = new MyBean();
        bean.setId(2);
        beanSet.add(bean);

        assertThat(beanSet, contains(
                hasProperty("id", is(1)),
                hasProperty("id", is(3))
                ));
    }
}
```

As you could see actual bean id's are `1` and `2` while expected ones are `1` and `3` so the test fails.

**Test result:**

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: iterable over [hasProperty("id", is <1>), hasProperty("id", is <3>)] in any order
     but: Not matched: <MyBean@4888884e
```

If I switch to `Matchers.contains()` method then the result is much more informative:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: iterable containing [hasProperty("id", is <1>), hasProperty("id", is <3>)]
     but: item 0: property 'id' was <2>
```

Unfortunately, since a Set is not ordered `contains()` is not an option in this case.

**Finally the question:**
Is it somehow possible to get a better error report when asserting a `Set` with hamcrest?

Comment: If you add a toString method to your MyBean you should get a better output...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hamcrest seems to have different implementations for how mismatches are reported for the `contains` and the `containsInAnyOrder` matchers.

The `containsInAnyOrder` just gives you the item's `toString()` value by doing this:

```
mismatchDescription.appendText("Not matched: ").appendValue(item);
```

While the `contains` matcher does a better job by delegating to the actual matcher's `describeMismatch()`:

```
matcher.describeMismatch(item, mismatchDescription);
```

Hence you see the `hasProperty` matcher's additional information in this case but not while using `containsInAnyOrder`.

I think the best you can do in this case is to implement a `toString()` for your `MyBean` class.

There is already an issue reported about this: https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/issues/47

Comment: considering that I have a lot of complex beans implementing `toString` will require quite an effort

Comment: Unfortunately I see no other way with the current state of Hamcrest. There is also an issue reported on this: https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/issues/47